# SQL 3-state flag query true false or both

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have the following situation:
Database contains fields 'sent' and 'success'. The application has a filter form which passes parameters to the query depending on user input. This can be sent, failed and/or success (or neither).
success is an INT field which can be null (no result), 0 (failed) and 1 (success) in combination with the sent field (should be 1 to have a success or failure). The query receives 3 parameters @sent, @failed and @success and depending on that, it should return nothing, success only, failed only or both. If @sent is 0, then it does not matter what success is
What I have so far:

```
    DECLARE @sent INT = 0
DECLARE @failed INT = 0
DECLARE @success INT  = 0
DECLARE @statusflagfail INT = NULL
DECLARE @statusflagsucc INT = NULL

IF @failed = 1 SET @statusflagfail = 0
IF @success = 1 SET @statusflagsucc = 1

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE   (Sent = @sent OR @sent = 0)
AND ((Sent = 1 AND Success = @statusflagsucc) OR @statusflagsucc IS NULL)
AND ((Sent = 1 AND Success = @statusflagfail) OR @statusflagfail IS NULL)
```

I know it would be easier to have 3 status fields, but it seems unlogical to me as theoretically you could then have both success and failed set for same record.

Any input would be apprecieated

Comment: Not sure what your question is?  Are you asking for input on the design?  I'd have a single status column myself.

Comment: side note, i'd use BIT instead of INT

Comment: I can't use a bit as Success column can be null, 0, 1

Comment: What I'm asking is that if eg I receive input sent = 1, failed = 0, success = 1 the query should return all that was sent successfully which means sent=1 and success=1. If received sent=1 and failed=1 and success=1 it should return rows where sent =1 and success=0 etc... if received sent=1 and failed=1 and success=1 it should return all rows where sent=1 and success = 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see only Sent=0, @Success=1 and @Failed=1 results I think you don't need extra variables. The following script should be enough for your need.

```
DECLARE @sent INT = 0
DECLARE @failed INT = 0
DECLARE @success INT  = 0

SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE   (Sent= 0)
OR (Sent = 1 AND Success = 1 AND (@success=1 or @failed=1) )
```